# Dynamic searching in windows forms

Tags: c#, ajax, winforms

I've just been set my software development assignment for my first term University project and have been planning out the UI.

Prior to being introduced to C# I spent a lot of time doing web development and became extremely familiar with AJAX.

I was wondering if there are any tools available in C#/Windows forms that provide real-time field refreshing upon a users input into a text box - any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: the field is refreshed, then it's value is changed

Comment: in winforms there's tooling out there like infragistics, component one and telerik, but they're paid... they have extra events like Beforekeydown, afterkeydown, beforevaluechanged, aftervaluechanged and stacks of customized events... theres not much in terms of good open source WinForms tools that ive seen.

Comment: Check out MVVM and it's databindings, there is an OnPropertyChanged event that get's fired notifying the UI to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as AJAX or like it in Windows Forms. Real-time field refreshing is done through several events. Let's say that you have a TextBox and a ComboBox (dropdownlist). The list contains a lot of items and you want to filter them using the textbox.

In that case you can use the TextChanged event of the TextBox and filter items from your initial itemscollection. After the filtering, bind the items to your ComboBox again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking that .TextChanged would offer the sort of functionality I was looking for but it's nice to get things clarified!